# How to check if Pepper is currently talking

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper

Is there a way to receive information if currently the robot is talking or not.
I have looked at ALDialog and ALTextToSpeech APIs, but couldn't find anything useful.

I am looking for something like `ALDialog.isSpeaking()` that returns 'True' if Pepper is currently saying something and 'False' if he is not talking at the moment of the method invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's various information posted in ALMemory whom you can subscribe, giving you information about speaking and even more precisely: which word currently spoken...

```
JVoyage [0] ~ $ qicli call ALMemory.getDataList ALTextToSpeech
["ALTextToSpeech/CurrentSentence","ALTextToSpeech/PositionOfCurrentWord",
"ALTextToSpeech/CurrentBookMark","ALTextToSpeech/TextStarted","ALTextToSpeech/TextDone",
"ALTextToSpeech/Status","ALTextToSpeech/CurrentWord","ALTextToSpeech/TextInterrupted"]
```

More details: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-api.html#ALTextToSpeech/Status

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a method like you describe but didn't find any.
I made a workaround where I check if the speakers are playing. That would be speaking, playing music, etc.

```
# initialize
self.boolSpeakersPlaying = True
self.audioDevice = self.session.service("ALAudioDevice")
self.signalID = self.audioDevice.speakersPlaying.connect(self.signalReceived)

#main
def signalReceived(self, arg):
self.logger.info("signal changed to = " + str(arg))
self.boolSpeakersPlaying = arg

def spam(self):
if not self.boolSpeakersPlaying:
    #do something
```